# How do I restrict Apache/SVN access to specific users (LDAP/file-based authentication)?

Tags: svn, authentication, active-directory, ldap, apache2

I have Apache/SVN running on Windows Server 2003 with authentication via LDAP/Active Directory and a flat-file.

It's working great except that *any* LDAP user can access everything. I'd like to be able to limit SVN repositories by user or group.

Ideally, I'd get to something like this:

```
<Location /svn/repo1>
  # Restricted to ldap-user1, file-user1, or members of ldap-group1,
  # all others denied
</Location>

<Location /svn/repo2>
  # Restricted to ldap-user2, file-user2, or members of ldap-group2,
  # all others denied
</Location>
```

The real trick might be that I have mixed authentication: LDAP and file:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath C:/svn_repository
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthBasicProvider ldap file
  AuthUserFile "svn-users.txt" #file-based, custom users
  AuthzLDAPAuthoritative On
  AuthLDAPBindDN ldapuseraccount@directory.com
  AuthLDAPBindPassword ldappassword
  AuthLDAPURL ldap://directory.com:389/cn=Users,dc=directory,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectCategory=person)
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

---

In my googling, I've seen some people accomplish this by pulling in the `authz` file like this:

```
<Location /svn>
  ...
  AuthzSVNAccessFile "conf/svn-authz.txt"
</Location
```

Then, I'd need to map the AD users. Any examples of that approach?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your configuration

Comment: Can you allow all read/write access but one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was actually a lot easier than I thought it would be. I added this to my location:

```
<Location /svn>
  ...
  AuthzSVNAccessFile "conf/svn-authz.txt"
</Location
```

In that file, I just specified normal SVN permissions (the system doesn't seem to distinguish between file users and LDAP users at this point):

```
[groups]
@admin = haren

###
### Deny all but administrators to the tree
###

[/]
* =
@admin = rw


###
### Allow more specific people on a per-repository basis below
###

[repo1:/]
ldap-user1 = rw
file-user1 = rw

[repo2:/]
ldap-user2 = rw
file-user2 = rw
```

I'm still playing around with the LDAP group syntax to get that part working. Any suggestions there are appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternate method for anyone else who is interested:

```
Require ldap-group cn=SVN Users,cn=Users,dc=company,dc=com
```

This is assuming you created a group called SVN Users in Active directory. Notice that there are no double quotes around the group.

Use that instead of Require valid-user

Then you probably don't have to restart apache anytime you have any changes, just add the user to the group in AD

Comment: Hi, if this is for a particular repo say for e.g test-repo, then what would be the permission in svn.acl file for test-repo? should it be *= rw or something else? I tried adding what you have mentioned to httpd.conf file for location /repos/test-repo but the test-repo is not seen by anyone including group SVN Users

Answer (score 0):

You should ***not*** use

```
Require valid-user
```

but use

```
Require group
```

Comment: What then is the syntax for a group?

Is it possible to put his info in the authz file so I don't have to restart apache after every change?