# svn access permissions for ldap authentication

Tags: svn, ldap

The svn server is on linux, and is authenticated thru LDAP. This is working fine, now that we need to set access level permission for certain users but there is no group in ldap. Please let me know how to achieve this. I tried the access control file, but its not working. 
There is a similar question already here in stackoverflow, which specified to use the access control file only, which is of no use.

Comment: Path-Based Authorization is not working? Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484499/how-do-i-restrict-apache-svn-access-to-specific-users-ldap-file-based-authentic

Comment: @FaustoCarvalhoMarquesSilva, I already checked that answer, and its not working though.

Answer (score 0):

> we need to set access level permission for certain users

- **If** they are ACLs for different parts *inside repository* (not for accessing repository per se), you **must** in any case to use [Path-Based Authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html): every Authenticated User, regardless of the method of the authorization, is user, which can be referenced in authz-file

> Some authentication systems expect and carry relatively short
>   usernames of the sorts we've been describing here—harry, sally, joe,
>   and so on. But other authentication systems—such as those which use
>   LDAP stores or SSL client certificates—may carry much more complex
>   usernames. For example, Harry's username in an LDAP-protected system
>   might be `CN=Harold Hacker,OU=Engineers,DC=red-bean,DC=com`. With
>   usernames like that, the access file can become quite bloated with
>   long or obscure usernames that are easy to mistype. Fortunately,
>   username aliases allow you to have to type the correct complex
>   username only once, in a statement which assigns to it a more easily
>   digestable alias.
>
> ```
> [aliases]
> harry = CN=Harold Hacker,OU=Engineers,DC=red-bean,DC=com
> sally = CN=Sally Swatterbug,OU=Engineers,DC=red-bean,DC=com
> joe = CN=Gerald I. Joseph,OU=Engineers,DC=red-bean,DC=com
> ```
>
> …
>
> Once you've defined a set of aliases, you can refer to the users
>   elsewhere in the access file via their aliases in all the same places
>   you could have instead used their actual usernames

- **If** you have to limit **access to repository** in principle and allow it only to *some* LDAP-users, you have to fine-tune [mod_authnz_ldap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html) settings and change `AuthLDAPURL` for your needs or use some other type of `Require` directive instead of `Require valid-user`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as you mentioned i need to limit access to repository, but i will not be able to use require directive, as the groups aren't there in LDAP.

Comment: @anand - don't use groups, you have a lot of another methods, groupless. *If LDAP-data can be edited** - `Require ldap-attribute` f.e., or just enumerate all users in `Require ldap-user`

Comment: I checked the directives of Require, these are good, but this fully restricts entry for a user, though we should give him read permission at-least.